# Decrypt data in a PostgreSQL query which was encrypted with C#

Tags: postgresql, encryption

There is some code we have in C# which encrypts and decrypts data for storing in a postgresql database. The code for decrypting is as follows:

```
public string Decrypt(string val)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    string[] split = val.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (string s in split)
    {
        sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decode(Convert.FromBase64String(s))));
        sb.Append(" ");
    }
    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1); // Remove last space

    return sb.ToString();
}

private static byte[] Decode(byte[] encodedData)
{
    var symmetricAlgorithm = Aes.Create();
    symmetricAlgorithm.Key = HexToByteArray("<aes key>");

    var hashAlgorithm = new HMACSHA256();
    hashAlgorithm.Key = HexToByteArray("<hash key>");

    var iv = new byte[symmetricAlgorithm.BlockSize / 8];
    var signature = new byte[hashAlgorithm.HashSize / 8];
    var data = new byte[encodedData.Length - iv.Length - signature.Length];

    Array.Copy(encodedData, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);
    Array.Copy(encodedData, iv.Length, data, 0, data.Length);
    Array.Copy(encodedData, iv.Length + data.Length, signature, 0, signature.Length);

    // validate the signature
    byte[] mac = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(iv.Concat(data).ToArray());

    if (!mac.SequenceEqual(signature))
    {
        // message has been tampered
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    symmetricAlgorithm.IV = iv;

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, symmetricAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        }
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}

private static byte[] HexToByteArray(string hex)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length).
        Where(x => 0 == x % 2).
        Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16)).
        ToArray();
}
```

The requirement I have now is that we want to be able to decrypt within an SQL query.. I have discovered the `PGP_SYM_DECRYPT` function, as well as some others like `Encode()`/`Decode()` for base64 strings and a `decrypt_iv()` function as well. Only I am uncertain how to use these to decrypt data.

Any crypto experts that could help me out here?

Alternatively, is there some equivalent of MSSQL's CLR functions for Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @JensV for his answer.. we finally came up with the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aes_cbc_mix_sha256_decrypt(data text, key text) RETURNS text
language plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
  res text;
  dataHex text;
  iv bytea;
  aes_key bytea;
  encrypted_data bytea;
BEGIN
  SELECT decode(key, 'hex') INTO aes_key;
  SELECT encode(decode(data, 'base64'), 'hex') INTO dataHex;
  SELECT decode(SUBSTRING(dataHex FROM 1 FOR 32), 'hex') INTO iv;
  SELECT decode(SUBSTRING(dataHex FROM 33 FOR (SELECT LENGTH(dataHex) - 32 - 64)), 'hex') INTO encrypted_data;
  SELECT encode(decrypt_iv(encrypted_data, aes_key, iv, 'aes-cbc'), 'escape') INTO res;
  RETURN res;
  
    EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
        RETURN data;
END;
$$
```

Answer (score 2):

So what I'm inferring from the decryption code is the following:

Your encodedData is split up into three parts

- Initialization vector (IV)
- Ciphertext
- Signature

You are using AES to encrypt/decrypt the data and use HMACSHA256 for the signature.

- [The AES block size in C# is fixed to 128 bits.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.blocksize?view=netcore-3.1)
- The signature is 256 bits in length (thus SHA256) [(ref)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256?view=netcore-3.1)
- The IV is blockSize / 8 bytes long -> 16 bytes
- Signature is 32 bytes

That means your encoded data is split up as follows:

```
[IV 16 bytes][Ciphertext n bytes][Signature 32 bytes]
```

To decrypt this with postgres, you need to have the `pgcrypto` module enabled. Lets say we have a table `Foo` with the field `data` of type `bytea` which contains the encrypted data. By using the [Raw Encryption Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html#id-1.11.7.34.8) of `pgcrypto` you should be able to decrypt this utilizing [binary string operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-binarystring.html) to extract the parts.

- `(octet_length(data) - 16 - 32)` should be the ciphertext length
- `substring(data from 0 for 16)` should get the IV
- `substring(data from 16 for (octet_length(data) - 16 - 32))` should get the ciphertext
- `substring(data from (octet_length(data) - 32) for 32` should get the signature.

This results in:

```sql
SELECT decrypt_iv(
    substring(data from 16 for (octet_length(data) - 16 - 32)),
    "Decryption Key as bytes"::bytea,
    substring(data from 0 for 16),
    'aes'
)
FROM Foo
```

The signature is disregarded in this example, but you should be able to verify it
in a similar way with [General Hashing Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html#id-1.11.7.34.5). If the decryption key is wrong, you will probably just get garbage data.

Comment: I appreciate the great response, but I am getting an error as follows:

"decrypt_iv error: Data not a multiple of block size".

Also, I am not 100% sure which decryption key you are referring to. I assume the AES one, but there is also a hash key.. so please confirm. In any case, I tried both and got the same error message. Would appreciate any assistance you can provide.

Comment: @Matt I mean the AES one. If you supply the key as a hex string, use the format `"\xDEADBEEF"`. The hash key is ingored (part of the signature, see last paragraph). If possible, could you provide an example data payload with a decryption key? (without sensitive data ofc)

Comment: @Matt providing the encryption code could also help if available

Comment: Thanks. Please see my answer for the final solution.. but I have rewarded you the +100 bounty, as you helped get us there.. with such a thorough explanation. Thanks